# Punishments for the manipulation of the justice system

Tags: criminal-law

I was wondering are the punishments for manipulating the justice system to your advantage based upon the severity of the result of the extent of manipulation or both. And what is the maximum punishment.

E.g. What would happen if you slandered someone in the news and spoke to judges to get someone on death row

Or for instance if you found out who the jury was and convinced them all that someone was guilty of extortion or other lesser crimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States, slander (libel if written, defamation in general) can be both criminal and civil depending on it's nature.  Slander, in the United States, is also highly dependent on how well known the plaintiff is to the general public.  What is slanderous against the small town farmer is late night comedy goal for the national politician.  Generally the former needs to only prove that the defamatory statement was factually true while the later needs to prove actual malice or negligent disregard for the truth.

If, while under oath, you knowingly testified to falsehoods, you have committed perjury, which is a felony offense.  So if I testify that "Bob killed Alice," while knowing that I murdered Alice, that's perjury.  However, if I testified that "Bob killed Alice," unaware until cross-examination that Bob had an identical twin brother Charlie, I have not commited perjury because I had no way to know that Bob looked like someone else.

If at a later date, it's proven that I committed perjury and that the defendant in the trial was wrongfully convicted and executed, then I have committed Felony Murder (Felony Murder occurs when someone dies as a direct result of your felony crime, regardless of your intent to actually kill them.  The typical example is the elderly woman who has a heart attack when the bank robber yells "This is a stick up".  Even if my gun is fake... even if I let medics taken her to the hospital...  Even if I don't kill any other hostages...)  If perjury is results in going to death row but being released prior to the actual exection, it would most likely be something akin to attempted murder... Perjury is a very serious crime in US Jurisprudence.

Your final question depends on the nature of the conviction.  If you were just some loud mouth talking at the bar of the hotel the Jury is sequestered in and that resulted in a conviction, then it might result in a mistrial being declared and the sentence being vacated.  The prosecution may or may not retry the case, depending on how strong they feel about doing it over.   If it resulted in the defense going free, it depends.  Normally, the matter would not be pushed for retrial as double jeopardy would get invoked and even then, the Prosecution would likely not want to try the case based on negative feed back they would likely get if they won

HOWEVER...

If you were involved with jury tampering to deliberatly get the defendant a "Not Guilty Plea" through nefarious means (Bribery, threats, ect.). than Double Jeopardy is voided for the trial (the logic is, since the defendant was never in danger of a finding against him, he was never in in Jeopardy in the first trial.  Thus a second trial with a clean jury would be the first time he would be in Jeopardy).  And yes, there is an actual case on this matter that found in that way in the U.S.  Beating a Murder Charge with a tampered Jury means you would face a second trial with both a Murder Charge and a Jury Tampering charge.

Answer (score 0):

### 14 years

In NSW, Australia, 14 years is the maximum term for [perverting the course of justice](http://phttps://www.armstronglegal.com.au/criminal-law/offences/false-statements/pervert-the-course-of-justice).